# Mapping a URI to string in Fluent NHibernate

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, orm, fluent-nhibernate

(See this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612010/mapping-a-uri-to-string-field-in-linq-to-sql) for LINQ-to-SQL)

I'd like to map a class that has a `URI` member to a `string` column using NHibernate. 
How exactly might I accomplish that?

I don't think the solution given to the related question works here - I can't declare a private field and map it, because the mapping needs to reference that field.

Comment: Ask a question, please - don't make us hunt for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless you need to do something special, `UriType` provided by NHibernate will work (I don't know what version it was introduced - I am using 3.1.4000). No need to write a custom user type.

### ClassMap

You can specify `UriType` in a `ClassMap<>`:

```
public class ImportedWebImageMap : ClassMap<ImportedWebImage>
{
    public ImportedWebImageMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id);
        Map(x => x.SourceUri).CustomType<UriType>();
    }
}
```

### Property Convention

You can use a property convention to map all `Uri` properties to use `UriType`:

```
public class UriConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (typeof(Uri).IsAssignableFrom(instance.Property.PropertyType))
            instance.CustomType<UriType>();
    }
}
```

### Storing as varchar

If you want to store the `Uri` in the database as `varchar` rather than the default `nvarchar` you can create a custom type that derives from `UriType` and specifies the `AnsiString` SQL type:

```
public class UriAnsiStringType : UriType
{
    public UriAnsiStringType()
        : base(new AnsiStringSqlType())
    { }

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return "UriAnsiStringType"; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The same solution would work fine; You could define the string property as private so it is not exposed to anyone.

Fluent NHibernate doesn't handle this as easily as standard HBM files, but it can be done a few ways.  See the [Fluent NHibernate Wiki](http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Fluent_mapping_private_properties) for instructions.

Alternatively, I think you'd have to define an IUserType class that can load/save the value as a string.  Example of doing this with Fluent NHibernate can be found [at the end of this blog post](http://blog.jagregory.com/2009/01/11/fluent-nhibernate-auto-mapping-type-conventions/).

Comment: Updated the question - I'm using Fluent NHibernate. How would such a mapping work? (Code sample if possible).

Comment: Added links to examples for both options.